# How to import LibGDX physics module?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working with the LibGDX framework and I'm trying this:

```java
World world = new World()
```

But I cannot import `com.badlogic.gdx.physics.World`, in gdx there is no physics module. I have imported `gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar` , `gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar`, `gdx.jar` and `gdx-natives.jar`

Comment: gdx-box2d (2d physics) is an extension which you need to add https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle

Answer (score 1):

When creating the project using new snapshot project creator make sure to check Box2d check box.

That should do the work.

Comment: I did not use this project creator , but It is solved. Now there is a new obstacle : CircleShape cshape = new CircleShape();
  cshape.setRadius(5);
  fdef.shape = cshape;
  body.createFixture(fdef); at third line there is an error , which says : cannot convert from cyrcleshape to shape , but in tutorial which I follow it works